# Lotus Notes multi day events

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, icalendar

I have a small service with creating and sending an email with "*inline*" attachment which contains `.ics` file with n-count events, how created using the ***ical4j library***.

- If I send it to Outlook/Gmail calendar it synchronizes correctly to all days.
- If I send it to Lotus Notes calendar it synchronizes only first day.

Is it Lotus Notes calendar feature or am I making some mistakes?

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/Gaputin97/MailSending/blob/master/src/main/java/com/business/ical/service/implementation/CreateCalendarImpl.java)

Thanks in advance

[Google Drive link to .ics file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MFHPZpCJFfMA-vtg-K67C_u5woamt7yS)

Comment: Could you include the content of the ICS file?  The problem may be in the final formatting of the multiple dates.

Comment: @teleman
Added, check

Comment: What if you change the METHOD to PUBLISH instead of REQUEST ?

Comment: @teleman
Nothing change, only first day synchronizes.
Lotus remove all events without first.
[link to modified ics](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aI9Ef0bTZae2ksKpFs5442nCiZrfSdJj)

Comment: A hexdump on the ICS file shows 3 characters/bytes preceding the BEGIN text -- "o;?"  Whatever is generating the ICS file is putting in those bytes which are not displayed in an editor.  Remove those 3 bytes and the file is readable for Notes calendar.

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom about the BOM, byte-order mark.  See if you can have the ICS file generated in UTF-8 without the BOM (EE BB BF).

Answer (score 0):

Set the Mime header for `Content-Type` in **iCal4J** for the iCal file:

```
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset="utf-8"
```